# How do I use an angular-js $resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm trying to use the angular-js $resource function while building an app with ionic framework. But I can't seem to make it work.
Relevant code:

**Service.js**

```
.factory('Pages', function($resource) {
    var source = $resource("http://localhost:5432/api/pages",{},
    {query: { method: "GET", isArray: false }});
    return source;
})
```

**controllers.js**

```
.controller('PagesCtrl', function($scope, Pages) {
$scope.pages =  Pages.query();
$scope.results = $scope.pages.results;
console.log($scope.results);
})
```

**browse.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Browse">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Browser</h1>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="page in results">
        <h2>{{page.title}}</h2>
      </ion-item>

    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

and the data

```
{
"count": 2,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "parent": null,
        "title": "Blog",
        "content": "<p>Blog</p>",
        "content_model": "richtextpage",
        "slug": "blog",
        "publish_date": null,
        "login_required": false,
        "meta_description": "Blog",
        "tags": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "parent": null,
        "title": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "content": "Lorem ipsum ....",
        "tags": ""
    }
]
}
```

But the console log (in controllers.js) will always print 'undefined'. I've been at it for hours and I can't seem to find what's wrong.

Comment: You received a couple of very good answers, so I'll only state the obvious for the sake of being thorough. Navigate to http://localhost:5432/api/pages in your browser and make sure that it's returning the data you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual result object of `.query()` is a promise that will hold the result at some point.

So at the moment you try to access the result property of your payload, it is likely that the request is not yet finish.

However, Angular `ng-repeat` statement has a built in support for promises so in your view, browse.html, if you do:

```
  <ion-item ng-repeat="page in pages.results">
```

Instead of dealing with a `$scope.results` in your controller, everything should looks better.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much. I couldn't find clear documentation on that anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is a bit rough to find but very thorough. The details about http calls and promises are in the ```$http``` section: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/api/ng/service/$http (```$resource``` being an abstraction over that)

Answer (score 2):

$scope.pages is a promise. To write to console you'll need to use a callback function like this:

```
$scope.pages = Pages.query();
$scope.pages.$promise.then(function (result) {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion for the service:

```
.factory('Pages', function($resource) {
    return {
       source: $resource("http://localhost:5432/api/pages",{},
                   { 
                      query: { 
                          method: "GET", 
                          isArray: false 
                      }
                    })
    }
})
```

and then in the ctrl:

```
.controller('PagesCtrl', function($scope, Pages) {
    $scope.pages =  Pages.source.query();
    $scope.results = $scope.pages;
    console.log($scope.results);
})
```

But you know that the query is returning only an object because you tell the `$resource` that your query doesn't return an Array (it is false).

This only have to work if your Backend is correct defined.